# Send php variable to above for preventing a loop

Tags: php, html, loops

i have a script where i use die to prevent a function's continuous loop. But if i place this above the html, the html script will stop as well so i place it below the html but all the variables get echoed below the actual website. How can i make sure this get's echoed to the place where i want it to be and not below the website? Or is there a different way than using die? This is the code of the function:

```
function QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $domain) {
    $port = 43;
    $timeout = 5;
    $errm = "<p1>No connection could be made</p1>";
    $fp = @fsockopen($whoisserver, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout) or die($errm); 
    fputs($fp, $domain . "\r\n");
    $out = "";
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $out .= fgets($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    $res = "";
    if((strpos(strtolower($out), "error") === FALSE) && (strpos(strtolower($out), "not allocated") === FALSE)) {
        $rows = explode("\n", $out);
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $row = trim($row);
            if(($row != ':') && ($row != '#') && ($row != '%')) {
                $res .= $row."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Where you want to come out from function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `break` breaks out of any loop, just use it instead of `die`.

Beware if you have nested loops, as break will only exit the innermost loop. Oddly enough, in php you can use break(2) to break from two loops. I would refrain from doing that though.

Answer (score 1):

`die();` stops all PHP execution. It's rare that you'd actually want to do that.

Instead you should look at the try - catch construct and throwing and catching exceptions.

```
function QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $domain) {
    try {
        $port = 43;
        $timeout = 5;
        $errm = "<p1>No connection could be made</p1>";
        $fp = @fsockopen($whoisserver, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);

        if (!fp) {
            throw new Exception ("Couldn't open socket.");
        }
        //after the exception is thrown, the rest of this block will not execute.

        fputs($fp, $domain . "\r\n");
        $out = "";
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $out .= fgets($fp);
        }
        fclose($fp);

        $res = "";
        if((strpos(strtolower($out), "error") === FALSE) && (strpos(strtolower($out), "not allocated") === FALSE)) {
            $rows = explode("\n", $out);
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                $row = trim($row);
                if(($row != ':') && ($row != '#') && ($row != '%')) {
                    $res .= $row."<br>";
                }
            }
        }
        return $res;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //this block will be executed if any Exception is caught, including the one we threw above.
        //you can handle the error here or rethrow it to pass it up the execution stack.
        return "";
    }

}
```

[PHP's Exceptions manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a control variable to avoid infinite looping.

```
$end_condition = false;
while (!$end_condition)
{
    //do the job
    if (conditions/are/met)
    {
        $end_condition = true;
    }
}
```